# how to get sub string of an integer value in DB2? how to use in query

Tags: db2, mainframe

how to get sub string of an integer in DB2?

Example:
1023123 must be given as 1023

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [VARCHAR](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000869.html) and [SUBSTR](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000854.html) functions. You will use something like this:

```
SUBSTR(VARCHAR(1023123), 1, 4)
```

Edit: based on your comment you'll need to use these as well:  [CASE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0005646.htm) and [LENGTH](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/flen.htm#flen).

Comment: Hi, in a table im having a field as location number- integer
it will have values in 7 or 8 digits.
my requirement is
i)if i have 8 digits i need the first 2 digits of the number
example: 12345678 - ans: 12
ii)if i have 7 digits i need the first digit alone presceding with zero
example: 1234567 - ans: 01

please help me in this